# How to put a button on a Map in Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

i am trying to pull a map in my applcation with interface builder using MKMapView but for some reason its not showing up. Also i want to add some button to this view by clicking which i can browse a file existing in my iphone.

Please provide me with the detial description as i am new to this.

Thanks,

Comment: You cannot simply drop a pin using only Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to add an annotation to the map, then provide a custom view for it.

To add an annotation to the map, adopt the **MKAnnotation** protocol in one of your objects and set its *coordinate* property to the appropriate lat/lon location.

Next, you'll add the annotation to the map using **MKMapView addAnnotation**.

Set the map's delegate property to your view controller, then implement **mapView:viewForAnnotation:**

When this method gets called, return a MKAnnotationView for your annotation.  Set the MKAnnotationView's **image** property to whatever image you want the annotation to use (an image of a button perhaps?).

You can implement **mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:** if you want to know when the annotation was selected.

You can also set a callout accessory button on the annotation using MKAnnotationView's **leftCalloutAccessoryView** and **rightCalloutAccessoryView** properties.  If you do this, you can then respond when the user selects the callout button by implementing **mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:**.

Comment: Actually what i am trying to do is, to pull a map in my applcation with interface builder using MKMapView but for some reason its not showing up. Also i want to add some button to this view by clicking which i can browse a file existing in my iphone.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *AnnotationViewID = @"annotationViewID";

     annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];

    if (annotationView == nil)
    {
        annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID] autorelease];
    }
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"s11.png"];

    annotationView.annotation = annotation;

    [annotationView setEnabled:YES];
    [annotationView setCanShowCallout:YES];

    return annotationView;
}
```

Comment: using this you can add button in the annotation of your pi,

Comment: Thanks for sharing this info but how can we simply pull a map through interface builder by drag n drop. I did the same thing but it didn't show up.

Thanks