# How to add button on an MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, mkmapview

I'm trying to make an iPhone app where the map has buttons, how do I do that? I've already implemented `MKMapView` and set its `longitude/latitude` and centered it where I want it.

Comment: at where you want to add button? explain exactly what you want?

Comment: I want a map that has buttons (I'm here) in like 10 different locations within a city. I don't want to manually put a button on top of the mkmapview so that when the map moves around, the button is still relative with the map

Answer (score 6):

You not elaborate your Question, so i guess that you want,

[Use  `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKUserTrackingBarButtonItemClassRef/Reference/Reference.html)

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];    
        MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc] initWithMapView:self.map];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItem;
    }
```

`AMKUserTrackingBarButtonItem` object is a specialized bar button item that allows the user to toggle through the user tracking modes. For example, when the user taps the button, the map view toggles between tracking the user with and without heading. The button also reflects the current user tracking mode if set elsewhere. This bar button item is associated to a single map view.

Also read this Question [How to put a button on a Map in Iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303919/how-to-put-a-button-on-a-map-in-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

Try it....

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinAnnotation = nil;
    if(annotation != myMapView.userLocation) 
    {
        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"myPin";
        pinAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        pinAnnotation = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[myMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if ( pinAnnotation == nil )
            pinAnnotation = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];

        pinAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;

        infoButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25)];
        [infoButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_go_map.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        pinAnnotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView = infoButton;
        [infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(detailBtnClk:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }    
    return pinAnnotation;
}
```

Hope i helped